# cmake: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by cmake)

Tags: arch-linux, glibc, cmake

I want to run `cmake` for a program,

```
[build]$ cmake ../
cmake: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by cmake)
```

I have this error, how i can fix it?
I use from Archlinux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrade **gcc-libs** & it's dependencies (libtool & gcc) to most recent version and the issue will be solved. Or you can simply execute following command:

```
sudo pacman -S libtool gcc gcc-libs
```

Comment: Must be a typical Arch issue, cf. also https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=181759 Subtracting the `-y` and the `-u` options, it's practically the same helpful line that you suggested in your answer.